# Why doesn't my Twitter button work in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, twitter

Go to this page for example: http://readme.readmedia.com/State-Treasurer-Fitzgerald-Reminds-Teachers-to-Register-for-Free-Pencils/1052815

Click the Twitter button to post it to Twitter. It works in every browser except Internet Explorer 7, including other versions of Internet Explorer.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or any alternative Twitter buttons that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried with IE7 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [official Twitter button](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton). It's easy to configure and it works.

Or you can get rid of JavaScript and use a simple URL with an encoded parameter.

```
http://twitter.com/?status=Here%20goes%20the%20url%20and%20a%20comment
```

[Try it](http://twitter.com/?status=Here%20goes%20the%20url%20and%20a%20comment). You can add it to your template like you did for the Digg button.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update the Java program on your PC. I was having the same problems. Before the update it did work with several other browsers, but not with Internet Explorer.

Edit: I have checked my version now. I was having this problem with IE 8, but after the update is was working fine for me.

Comment: "Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster" There's absolutely no relation.